# How to sum a range of values in one column based on a range as defined by a multiindex

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I'm well and truly stumped on this

I have a MultiIndex dataframe that looks like this

```
               data
index1 index2  
0      1       8
       2       7
       3       6
       4       9
1      1       3
       2       4
       3       3
       4       6
2      1       5
       2       5
```

.... and so on

and I'm trying to sum a load of values from the data column for each index1 based on a range of values from index2 to create a new dataframe.

i.e. if I were to create a new dataframe from the data values that correspond to the first 2 values of index2 per index1 from the example above I would want to get,

```
index1 summed_data
0      15
1      7
2      10
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change your input format, using the following statement：

```
x = df.groupby(level ='index1').agg({'data': lambda x: x[:2].sum()}).rename(columns = {'data':'summed_data'})
```

Then print：

```
        summed_data
index1             
0                15
1                 7
2                10
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. That's one more speed bump out of the way in getting this data sorted. Seems I need to better learn how to use the .agg and lambda functions

Comment: Unfortunately I can't publicly upvote until I hit 15 rep. 3 more questions and I'll have enough to start upvoting ^_^

Comment: It's my fault, ha ha